# prove that for an idempotent matrix, trace=rank

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics

prove that for an idempotent matrix, trace=rank

Comment: How do you know the trace is an integer? I only know the $\chi^2$-distribution with an integer parameter.

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva: I doubt that an integer argument for $tr(A)$ is implied.  The [chi-squared distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_distribution) is for a sum of $k$ squares of normally distributed independent standard normal random variables, but here $tr(A)$ must be playing the role of the sum of squares.  The degrees of freedom $k$ must depend on the dimension of $A$.

Comment: @samuel11: You completely changed the question from one about probability to one about linear algebra.  Please refrain from doing this in the future.  If you wish, you may self-delete a question if it has no Accepted or up-voted answer.  A new question deserves a separate post.

Answer (score 4):

An idempotent matrix is trivially diagonalizable. If two matrices are similar they have the same rank and trace. So it suffices to assume your matrix is diagonal.

$$D^2=D \iff d_{ii}^2=d_{ii} \iff d_{ii}\in \{0,1\}$$

The number of nonzero diagonal entries in $D$ (the rank) is therefore equal to the trace.